# Two websites with a domain and subdomain

Tags: asp.net, web, dns, subdomain

I've got a ASP.NET website which has a domain name. I've got another web solution, and I want to route this solution to subdomain. 
Example :

I've got website which has a www.mydomain.com domain name,

And I want to give domain name like sub.mydomain.com.

Any help would be great. I'm a newbie in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your dns settings and how easy they are to control.  If you have a cPanel provided by your hosting company this is usually easy to do.  The websites have to be on the same url usually but a sub domain can forward to an external website.

Contact your hosting company/domain provider about using sub domains.